# How to populate select ng-options with JSON object that has an string array?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, sorting, grouping

currently I have this JSON object:

```
 {
    "hospitalId" : "0002",
    "name" : "test form",
    "procedureId" : "0002-testform",
    "steps" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Brand",
            "value" : [ 
                "jonson", 
                "smith", 
                "braun"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "Procedure type",
            "value" : [ 
                "total", 
                "unicompartimental"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I need to display it on a multiselect, like this:

```
<strong>Brand</strong>
<ul>braun</ul>
<ul>jonson</ul>
<ul>smith</ul>

<strong>Procedure type</strong>
<ul>total</ul>
<ul>unicompartimental</ul>
```

They need to be ordered by steps.title and by steps.value, the thing is: I can't figure out how to display them correctly with a `<select ng-options>` tag, this is what I've tried:

```
<select multiple ng-model="step" ng-options="step[0].value  group by step.title for step in loadedSteps.steps " ></select>
```

Gives me: **Brand** undefined

```
<select multiple ng-model="step" ng-options="step.value  group by step.title for step in loadedSteps.steps | orderBy:['value']"></select>
```

Gives me: **Brand** [jonson, smith, braun]

Also I've tried with a nested `<option>` but it doesn't have ordering...

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer you are looking for.

You should use two `ng-repeat`, first for displaying `title` and other for displaying `values` inside the title.

The first `ng-repeat` starts with the title and ends with the values in that title.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = 
 {
 "hospitalId": "0002",
 "name": "test form",
 "procedureId": "0002-testform",
 "steps": [{
  "title": "Brand",
  "value": [
   "jonson",
   "smith",
   "braun"
  ]
 }, {
  "title": "Procedure type",
  "value": [
   "total",
   "unicompartimental"
  ]
 }]

}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div >
      <label>{{step.title}}</label>
    <select>
    <option ng-repeat-start="step in names.steps | orderBy:'title'" ng-bind="step.title"></option>
    <option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="opt in step.value | orderBy:'step.value':true" ng-bind="' - ' + opt"></option>
    </select>
    
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Please run this snippet**

[HEre is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2WmjDOM67K0RbWN34CS6?p=preview)

Comment: @Camilo, please check this answer.

Comment: Thank you mate, it worked just fine, I appreciate it!